# Handling a Firebase notification in any activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/#comment-2952759611

I am able to send Firebase notifications to an Android app.

My class which extends the Firebase messaging service is

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        handleNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody);
    }

    private void handleNotification(String title, String body) {
        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("title", title);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", body);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        } else {
            // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
        }
    }
}
```

In one of my activities I have a listener defined and all other activities extend this class

```
public class DisplayNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_notification);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // process notification
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of a class which extends DisplayNotificationActivity is:

```
public class ListNotificationsActivity extends DisplayNotificationActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_notifications);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // process notification
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I am on the DisplayNotificationActivity activity when I receive a notification everything works as expected, but if I am on another activity such as ListNotificationsActivity then the DisplayNotificationActivity onCreate method is called, not the onCreate in the active activity.

How do I have the current activity handle the receiving of a notification on any activity without repeating the same code in all activities?

Edit: I do pause and resume the activity, this code is in DisplayNotificationActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));
            NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Unregister the receiver in onPause of the every Activity and register it to onResume of every activity. It will helps you. Because when you will be in ListNotificationsActivity then that registered receiver will get unregister for DisplayNotificationActivity.

Comment: I edited my post - I am pausing/resuming

Comment: Extend your every activity by `BaseActivity` do the process from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity `DisplayNotificationActivity` is super class for activity `ListNotificationsActivity` and you have called `super.onCreate()` method in `ListNotificationsActivity` that definitely will call super method onCreate of your super class i.e.  `DisplayNotificationActivity`.

Now for solution what you can do is use interface:

```
    public abstract class DisplayNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_notification);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // process notification
                   onNotificationReceived(your notification message);
            }
        }
    }
     public void onNotificationRecieved(String notiMessage);
 }
```

And on your `ListNotificationsActivity` :

```
public class ListNotificationsActivity extends DisplayNotificationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_notifications);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRecieved(String notiMessage) {
        //process your notification
    }
}
```

I have not run the code see if this works.

Comment: This still means I have to repeat the process of handling the notification on every activity

Comment: You don't have to set broadcast receiver in every activity you just handle message. If this is not what you want then you can handle notification in MyFirebaseMessagingService  why the need of BroadCastReceiver then?